# Play 2.1 - WS API - Missing Type Param Compile Error - WS.url(...).get().map { r => ... }

Tags: playframework-2.1

The error `missing parameter type` for `response` is given when I try to compile this code which comes (almost) directly from the [Play 2.1 Docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaWS)

```
def feedTitle(feedUrl: String) = Action {
  Async {
    WS.url(feedUrl).get().map { response =>
      Ok("test")
    }
  }
}
```

So then I give it a type like this, `{response: WS.Response => ...}` but then I get this error:

```
type mismatch;
found : play.libs.WS.Response => play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[String]
required: play.libs.F.Function[play.libs.WS.Response,?]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your imports are wrong. It should be `play.api.libs.ws.WS` instead of `play.libs.WS.Response`.

See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.Response

Comment: I changed the parameter type to `play.api.libs.ws.Response` but I'm left with pretty much the same error: `type mismatch;` `found : play.api.libs.ws.Response => play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[String]` `required: play.libs.F.Function[play.libs.WS.Response,?]`

Comment: I know someone with a 7k rep can answer this. Know of an samples of WS.url used in the wild (e.g., a github project)?

Comment: I figured it out... I made an answer but if you update yours I'll delete my answer and accept yours since you were 99% right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I imported `play.libs.WS` and not `play.api.libs.ws.WS` (notice the *api* package). I had to also import `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` but the error message told me to do so, so that was simple.